# Android: buildTypes applicationIdSuffix error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build-type, android-gradle-2.0

I want to setup a project to build two different apks that can be installed on the same device - one of them a production apk and the second one a debug apk. To do this I've defined in the build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {

        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }

    }
```

but when I try to sync the gradle I get the error:

```
Error:org.gradle.api.GradleException: No matching client found for package name 'mypkg.debug'
```

Aside from the buildTypes section of build.gradle, what else should I do to make this work properly?

Comment: Which gradle task throws this error?

Comment: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myApp:processDebugGoogleServices'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to provide a  google-service.json for every build flavor. In your case you need a debug one.

Generate a new one with the new package name (the original package name + .debug). Then put the json into **app/src/debug/**.

Comment: It's fine to duplicate your existing `google-service.json` and just modify the `package_name` to be `com.foo.bar.debug`. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file

Comment: Thanks @david_adler. That explains also how to deal with different flavors, that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Tried just copying the Google services, I am still getting this error

Comment: didn't work. Adding a package name +.debug will break oauth clients with Firebase etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @jbarat works. For Firebase authentication @giorgio79 you have to add SHA certificates to the project for the debug app in the settings of the firebase console.
To get the SHA1 and SHA256 certificates, enter the following commands in your terminal(command differ from OS)

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

Copy the debug SHA certificates and add them.