# Flutter, how to have release and debug app on the same device?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working with flutter on an application (only android for now) which can be downloaded from Google Play.
I have installed the released app on my phone. However, whenever I launch the debug on my device with android studio, it is deleting the released version.
What I would want is having both apps at the same time, like *"App"* and *"App_debug"* on my device.

How can I set up my project so there is no conflict between the debug and the release app ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to found a solution (only for android).

To not delete the *"released App"* download from Google Play, I add these lines in the file `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        // ------ Start Changes -----
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        // ----- End Changes -----
    }
}
```

In that way the package will be `com.example.app` for a release app and `com.example.app.debug` for my debug app and there is no conflict anymore.

---

However I also wanted a different app name so I can differenciate both apps.
To do so I followed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24786371/12066144):

In the file `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` I made this change:

```xml
<manifest ...>
    <application
        // before : android:label="App"
        android:label="@string/app_name"    // <- After my changes
    >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then to set up the name for the release app, create or modify the file `android/app/src/main/res/values/string.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App</string>
</resources>
```

And for the debug version, create or modify the file `android/app/src/debug/res/values/string.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App Debug</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
[        ] > No matching client found for package name 'com.myapp.debug'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609868/android-buildtypes-applicationidsuffix-error

Comment: You have no idea how much time you've just saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What're you looking for is called `flavors`. You can check out more info about it in the [flutter official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) or checking out these packages:

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavor
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr